# MongoDB - strip non numeric characters in field

Tags: regex, mongodb, mlab

I have a field of phone numbers where a random variety of separators have been used, such as:

```
932-555-1515
951.555.1255
(952) 555-1414
```

I would like to go through each field that already exists and remove the non numeric characters.

Is that possible?

Whether or not it gets stored as an integer or as a string of numbers, I don't care either way. It will only be used for display purposes.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over all your docs in code and use a regex replace to clean up the strings.

Here's how you'd do it in the mongo shell for a `test` collection with a `phone` field that needs to be cleaned up.

```js
db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.phone = doc.phone.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); 
  db.test.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: The `db.collection.save` method was deprecated and it's now removed from the latest MongoDB versions. One could use `db.collection.updateOne` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Starting in `Mongo 4.4`, the [`$function`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/function/index.html) aggregation operator allows applying a custom javascript function to implement behaviour not supported by the MongoDB Query Language.

And coupled with improvements made to [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) in `Mongo 4.2` that can accept an aggregation pipeline, allowing the update of a field based on its own value,

We can manipulate and update a field in ways the language doesn't easily permit and avoid an inefficient find/foreach pattern:

```
// { "x" : "932-555-1515",   "y" : 3 }
// { "x" : "951.555.1255",   "y" : 7 }
// { "x" : "(952) 555-1414", "y" : 6 }
db.collection.updateMany(
  { "x": { $regex: /[^0-9]/g } },
  [{ $set:
    { "x":
      { $function: {
          body: function(x) { return x.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ''); },
          args: ["$x"],
          lang: "js"
      }}
    }
  }
])
// { "x" : "9325551515", "y" : 3 }
// { "x" : "9515551255", "y" : 7 }
// { "x" : "9525551414", "y" : 6 }
```

---

The update consist of:

- a match query `{ "x": { $regex: /[^0-9]/g } }`, filtering documents to update (in our case any document that contains non-numeric characters in the field we're interested on updating).
- an update aggreation pipeline `[ { $set: { active: { $eq: [ "$a", "Hello" ] } } } ]` (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator and an alias for `$addFields`.

`$function` takes 3 parameters:

- `body`, which is the function to apply, whose parameter is the string to modify. The function here simply consists in replacing characters matching the regex with empty characters.
- `args`, which contains the fields from the record that the `body` function takes as parameter. In our case, `"$x"`.
- `lang`, which is the language in which the `body` function is written. Only `js` is currently available.

Comment: Super, thanks. I was almost there but the custom replace function was what I needed instead of the `$replaceAll` which doesn't accept regex in it's `find` parameter. This saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: Unfortunately, `$function` doesn't work on [serverless instances](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/serverless-instance-limitations/#unsupported-actions).

Answer (score 3):

Based on the previous example by @JohnnyHK, I added regex also to the find query:

```
/*
MongoDB: Find by regular expression and run regex replace on results
*/
db.test.find({"url": { $regex: 'http:\/\/' }}).forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.url = doc.url.replace(/http:\/\/www\.url\.com/g, 'http://another.url.com'); 
  db.test.save(doc);
});
```

Comment: The `db.collection.save` method was deprecated and it's now removed from the latest MongoDB versions. One could use `db.collection.updateOne` instead.

Answer (score 1):

in mongodb version 4.2 you have [regexFind project operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexFind/) which can be used together with [substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) inside an aggregation without looping through all the documents in client

Comment: Could you show an example on how to do that?