# I want to remove special character in MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an issue with special character in collection. I have huge number of documents in a collection. I want to loop through all the document for particular field and if there is any special character (period) present in that field value then i want to remove that special character.  Please note i did not include full document structure as its huge document. Just mentioned only the field name for the reference.

Currently i have totalValue like this. I want to remove only period (.) in the value part

"totals" : {"totalValue" : "2196.65"}

I want to make it like this after the update query

"totals" : {"totalValue" : "219665"}

Please share me the details of how to fix this.

Comment: Do you want to update that for all documents?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB - strip non numeric characters in field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005269/mongodb-strip-non-numeric-characters-in-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the input document `{ totals: { totalValue: "2196.65" } }`, the following aggregation query will update the document to 
`{ totals: { totalValue: "219665" } }`.

```
db.test.aggregate( [
  { $addFields: { index: { $indexOfCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", "." ] } } },
  { $match: { index: { $ne: -1 } } },
  { $project: { "totals.totalValue": { $concat: [ { $substrCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", 0, "$index" ] }, 
                                                  { $substrCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", { $add: [ "$index", 1 ] }, 99 ] } 
                                                ] 
  } } },
] ).forEach( doc => db.test.updateOne( { _id: doc._id }, { $set: { "totals.totalValue": doc.totals.totalValue } } ) );
```

This also updates all the documents in the collection.

Note that in case not all documents are with the "." embedded within the field, the filter is added to the query to not process those documents.

---

This is *another way* of achieving the same functionality using the `updateMany` method - works with **MongoDB 4.2** version or later.

```
var queryFilter = { $cond: {
                       if: { $eq: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", "." ] }, -1 ] },
                       then: false,
                       else: true
                     }
};

db.test.updateMany(
  { $expr: { $eq: [ queryFilter,  true ] } },
  [
    { $set: { 
          "totals.totalValue": { 
               $concat: [ 
                   { $substrCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", 0, { $indexOfCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", "." ] } ] }, 
                   { $substrCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", { $add: [ { $indexOfCP: [ "$totals.totalValue", "." ] }, 1 ] }, 99 ] } 
               ]            
          }
    } }
  ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this with `replace`:

```
db.totals.find({totalValue: {$regex: "."}}).forEach(function(doc, i) {
    doc.totalValue = doc.totalValue.replace(/\./, "");
    db.totals.save(doc);
})
```